# print "m"th column of "n"th line after a match if found in a file using awk

Tags: awk

I need to print 6th line after a particular **pattern** is found in a **file**. In that 6th line, I want to print only the 5th column. I can do the first part of this problem using the following command,

`awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=6}' file`

but I can't find a way to modify it to print just the 5th column of this 6th line instead. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define a column? Is it something like the 6th word? Write another regex that extaracts the 6th word.

Comment: the line is "The flux for the source 2.34". I want to extract 2.34 out of this line.

Comment: see my answer for more, but `print $5` will do what you want (though actually in your example it's actually `print $6`).

Comment: yeah, that was a typo, sorry, but thanks your solution works !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`NR`](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web) variable for this

```
awk '/pattern/ { nrs[NR + 6] = 1; } NR in nrs { print $5; delete nrs[NR] }'
```

This will test for `pattern` and make an entry in an array of the it's line number plus six (`NR + 6`). We then do a simple lookup on that array to see if our current line-number is one we want to print (`nrs[NR] == 1`) and then print the 5th column (`print $5`) and then clean up the array.

This solution accounts for the fact that a pattern might occur multiple times within any given 6 line range.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to really think about and ask questions if you don't understand a script you're using.

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=6}' file
```

is just using default behavior as shorthand for

```
awk 'c&&!--c{print $0} /pattern/{c=6}' file
```

which you can trivially tweak to:

```
awk 'c&&!--c{print $5} /pattern/{c=6}' file
```