# AWK, rename string only on n-th line after pattern match

Tags: awk, row, line, rename, multiline

Hi i have problem i cannot rename just only 1st occurence placed on 9th row of string after/since matched pattern

this is input (file containing 30k lines):

```
This is pattern 
patternvalue=dom.value.5.row.2
design=12
face=x1-m
omit=11
mode=OFF
option=955
display=x1-11-OFF
type=2
name=8a9s7fa645sdf              
resolution=0    
prio=OK 
number of pattern values:   
pattern values  
id=hex00.EA 
name=4fda6sd4f                  
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.EF 
name=as7e8w87e                  
patternvalue=dom.value.5.row.8
design=1
face=x1-n
omit=12
mode=OFF
option=95
display=x1-22-ON
type=2
name=8a9sad8f               
resolution=0    
prio=OK 
number of pattern values:   
pattern values  
id=hex00.0A 
name=dsf79                  
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.AA 
name=777777s                
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.BB 
name=777777l                
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.CC 
name=777777m
```

i tried this, but its renaming on  all strings "name"

```
 awk '/This is pattern/ && NR==10 ; sub(/name/,"patternname")1' num
```

"_https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678717/print-mth-column-of-nth-line-after-a-match-if-found-in-a-file-using-awk"

```
This is expected output:

This is pattern 
patternvalue=dom.value.5.row.2
design=12
face=x1-m
omit=11
mode=OFF
option=955
display=x1-11-OFF
type=2
patternname=8a9s7fa645sdf           
resolution=0    
prio=OK 
number of pattern values:   
pattern values  
id=hex00.EA 
name=4fda6sd4f                  
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.EF 
name=as7e8w87e                  
This is pattern 
patternvalue=dom.value.5.row.8
design=1
face=x1-n
omit=12
mode=OFF
option=95
display=x1-22-ON
type=2
patternname=8a9sad8f                
resolution=0    
prio=OK 
number of pattern values:   
pattern values  
id=hex00.0A 
name=dsf79                 
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.AA 
name=777777s                
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.BB 
name=777777l                
number of pattern values:   
id=hex00.CC 
name=777777m    

Thank you for any hints
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be ok:

```
awk '/This is pattern/{n=NR};NR==n+9{sub(/name/,"patternname")};1'
```

Some comments about your try.
You wrote

`awk '/This is pattern/ && NR==10 ; sub(/name/,"patternname")1' num`

awk commands follow the pattern

`condition1{action1};condition2{action2};....`

If the `{action}` part is missing, the default action is `{print}`.

If the `condition` part is missing, the default condition is `1` (=always true)

As a result , your awk script equals to this:

```
awk '/This is pattern/ && NR==10{print};sub(/name/,"patternname"){print};1{print}'
```

Moreover, awk internal variable `NR` holds the line number being processed of the input file.

As a result the first part of your script `'/This is pattern/ && NR==10{print}` prints the line only when `This is pattern` found and `NR` (line number) is `10`  meaning never in your case.

The second part of your script `sub(/name/,"patternname"){print}`, uses the function `sub` as a condition to print the line. 
So for every line being processed, `sub` tries to replace `name` with `patternname`. if this replacement is sucessfull , the line is then `{print}`.

The third part of your script `1{print}` , prints all the other lines, since the condition is `1` (always true).

About my solution:

First part `/This is pattern/{n=NR}`, holds in a temp variable `n` the line number `NR` in which `This is pattern` was found.

Second part `NR==n+9{sub(/name/,"patternname")}` compares `NR` (line number being processed by awk) to `n+9` (line number of `This is Pattern` + 9 more lines), and when this condition becomes true, then `name` is replaced by `patternname` using `sub` which is enclosed in `{...}` to dictate that this is the action part of the `NR==n+9` condition.

Third part `1` , just prints all the other lines (condition `1`==`true` , action is missing , default action `{print}` is performed)

Comment: Don't use the letter `l` as a variable name, it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.